# How can I mock the Geolocation API error function and !navigator.geolocation case in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, geolocation

I use the Geolocation API in a React app and I want to test it in Jest. This is my Geolocation function in the app:

```
const getGeolocation = () => {
    const success = position => {
        const {latitude} = position.coords
        const {longitude} = position.coords

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-magic-numbers
        map.current.setView([latitude, longitude], 12)
    }

    const error = () => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-magic-numbers
        map.current.setView([46.378333, 13.836667], 12)
    }

    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-magic-numbers
        map.current.setView([46.378333, 13.836667], 12)
    } else {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error)
    }
}
```

I'm able to test the `success` function, but I can't reach the `error` function and I also was not able to mock the `!navigator.geolocation` case. This is my mock:

```
const mockGeolocation = {
    getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()
        .mockImplementationOnce(success => Promise.resolve(success({
            coords: {
                latitude: 46.378333,
                longitude: 13.836667,
            },
        }))),
    watchPosition: jest.fn(),
}

global.navigator.geolocation = mockGeolocation
```

**How can I mock the `error` function and the `!navigator.geolocation` case?**

Comment: create an empty object navigator and use the same for mocking this scenario

Comment: Thank you! :-) That works for the `!navigator.geolocation` case, but do you also have an idea how to trigger the `error` function?

Comment: just return promise.reject to test error function and return error object.

  getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()
        .mockImplementationOnce(()=> Promise.reject( {error: 'error'}))

Comment: Hmmm, but now I get an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning and the `error` function code is not executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock it like this:

```
const mockGeolocation = {
    getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()
        .mockImplementationOnce((success, error) => Promise.resolve(error({
            code: 1,
            message: 'GeoLocation Error',
        }))),
    watchPosition: jest.fn(),
}

global.navigator.geolocation = mockGeolocation
```

Comment: Tried your solution but got error in the geolocation

"Cannot assign to 'geolocation' because it is a read-only property"